# Query a field wiith md5 version of id

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

**EDITED TO ADD MORE INFO**

I need to use mysql's md5 function to select an item using it's id field (`uid`). I have a separate database from my users called `recover_db` that has an md5 hashed value of the user id in it and a time stamp.

Currently the users visit a link like this:

```
recover-MD%HASHEDUSERID.html
```

Then the system takes that `MD%HASHEDUSERID` from the url and checks if it exists in the `recover_db` and if it does it lets them recover the account. There's some other stuff for security and whatnot but I do not store the user id in the `recover_db`, just the MD5 value of it. I use the following to do that:

```
md5(90*13/12*56+$id)
```

Now I need to check the users database and get the REAL account id using the md5 value I have saved. I was using the following query to do this:

```
$query = "SELECT uid FROM users where md5(90*13/12*56+uid)='".$md5accID."'";
```

Unfortunately this is returning no results. Is there any way to get the real user id from the `users` database using the md5 version of it from the `recover_db`? I want to avoid storing the user id in the `recover_db` if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the original user ID in a field `origuid` together with the hash (`hasheduid`) in the recovery database. Then do

```
$query = "SELECT origuid FROM users where hasheduid='".$md5accID."'";
```

to retrieve the original user ID.

Comment: I updated the question a bit since you posted. I was editing it to word it better when you replied lol. While this suggestion would work, I would like to avoid storing the **REAL** user id on the recover_db if possible. If it's not possible though then I will store it that way and change my md5 thing a bit.

Comment: As much as I dont wanna store the real userid in the db, I decided its easier this way.